# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification coming when input view for textfield is different

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I am using date picker as input view for textfield.
In view will appear I have added `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.

My problem is that when the date picker is to be seen then also it comes `KeyboardWillShowNotification` method. How can I differentiate that keyboard is seen or date picker is seen, as I need to resize table view according to that

I have assigned inputview in `textfieldDidBeginEditing`

```
cell.txtField.inputView = datePicker;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement the `(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` delegate and then save a local variable that you are editing your textfield at the moment like

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   self.editingTextfield = YES;
}
```

and in your `(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` you set that flag to `false`

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   self.editingTextfield = NO;
}
```

in your `KeyboardWillShowNotification` notification you can check that flag to see which control issued the keyboard